# openvpn routing

Tags: networking, openvpn

So far I have successfully created a virtual link between server A and server B using an unencrypted openvpn tunnel. I am trying to route some of server B's traffic through server A.
Server B has 5 external IPs and I would like to add 5 local vpn IPs that redirect traffic to 5 IPs at server A, which would give server B 10 distinct outgoing IPs to the world. Obviously some routing needs to be done on both servers but I'm not getting anywhere after a day of googling and reading.

I did

```
ip route add default via 10.0.0.2 dev tun0 table vpn_table
ip rule add from 10.0.0.1/32 table vpn_table
ip rule add to 10.0.0.2/32 table vpn_table
ip route flush cache
```

on server B, and the same on server A but with IPs swapped. However, on server B when I do `wget --bind-address=10.0.0.1 somewebsite` it's not working, I guess because server A doesn't know what to do with the request.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT

Someone suggested that server A doesn't need ip rules, so the situation I have right now is:

1. setup openvpn link
2. on server B I do the four ip command mentioned above

I think I'm still missing some routing info on server A. This is what tcpdump on server A outputs when I do `wget --bind-address=10.0.0.1 http://www.cnn.com` on server B:

```
tcpdump: WARNING: arptype 65534 not supported by libpcap - falling back to cooked socket
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 96 bytes
07:11:58.787908 IP 10.0.0.1.42802 > 157.166.248.10.80: S 2416144580:2416144580(0) win 14600 <mss 1410,sackOK,timestamp 858359606 0,nop,wscale 7>
07:11:59.786129 IP 10.0.0.1.42802 > 157.166.248.10.80: S 2416144580:2416144580(0) win 14600 <mss 1410,sackOK,timestamp 858359856 0,nop,wscale 7>
07:12:01.788535 IP 10.0.0.2 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP host 157.166.248.10 unreachable, length 68
07:12:01.788545 IP 10.0.0.2 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP host 157.166.248.10 unreachable, length 68
```

Wget on Server B says

```
Connecting to www.cnn.com (www.cnn.com)|157.166.248.11|:80... failed: No route to host.
```

**EDIT 5/19/2014**

Added SNAT on server A, right now tcpdump on server A is giving me (93.184.216.119 = www.example.com, 1.2.3.4 = server A's external IP that is now the source of packets coming from 10.0.0.1)

```
09:29:44.114475 IP 10.0.0.1.54691 > 93.184.216.119.80: S 717252699:717252699(0) win 14600 <mss 1410,sackOK,timestamp 903625938 0,nop,wscale 7>
09:29:45.113546 IP 10.0.0.1.54691 > 93.184.216.119.80: S 717252699:717252699(0) win 14600 <mss 1410,sackOK,timestamp 903626188 0,nop,wscale 7>
09:29:47.116587 IP 1.2.3.4 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP host 93.184.216.119 unreachable, length 68
09:29:47.116668 IP 1.2.3.4 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP host 93.184.216.119 unreachable, length 68
09:29:47.119289 IP 10.0.0.1.54691 > 93.184.216.119.80: S 717252699:717252699(0) win 14600 <mss 1410,sackOK,timestamp 903626689 0,nop,wscale 7>
09:29:50.120591 IP 1.2.3.4 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP host 93.184.216.119 unreachable, length 68
```

So it looks like SNAT on server A is working but somehow it is unable to connect to the requested website.
Server A iptables list:

```
SNAT       all  --  10.0.0.1             anywhere            to:1.2.3.4
```

Server A ip rule list:

```
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Part of server A 'route -n':

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

Could the gateway being 0.0.0.0 have something to do with it?

Comment: This is not a pure routing issue. You cannot communicate with the rest of the world using `10.0.0.1/32`. There has to be some NAT. So what does the other system do with the packets? You can track them with `tcpdump -i tun0 -n`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I have edited my original post with tcpdump info

Comment: You should not use `route -n` but `ip route`. I guess the `0.0.0.0` doesn't matter because `tun0` is a `POINTOPOINT` connection. Probably the `0.0.0.0` just means "no gateway IP has been set". I must admit I have no idea what's up there.

Comment: Ok, thanks. FWIW, here's part of the ip route output:

10.0.0.1 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.2

Comment: @HaukeLaging Got it working, thanks a lot for your help!

Problem was I had added some of the IPs on server A to eth1 which I just found out is not physically connected to the switch at the ISP :-/ . Re-added the IPs to eth0 and it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. It doesn't make sense to route packets to where they come from. I.e. the

   ```
   ip rule add from 10.0.0.1/32 table vpn_table
   ```

   must be left out on server A (`ip rule add to...` is not necessary either); server A has "normal" routing. You need such a rule on server B (for B's IP address), though.
2. You need SNAT on server A. Something like

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.1 -j SNAT --to-source 1.2.3.4
   ```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Not quite working yet, see my edits above.

Comment: @Martin Is routing enabled on server A at all? `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` + `iptables -L FORWARD -nv`

Comment: IP forwarding is on (cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward results in 1).

iptables -L FORWARD -nv
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination